# Sending mail with html file output as body

Tags: mailx

I'm receiving file hc.html as an attachment. But I wanted the output of hc.html as Body in Lotus Notes 8. I was using sendmail earlier and it was working fine for Outlook. In this new environment I cannot use sendmail. I can only use mailx.

Can anything can be done for this?

```
(cat body.txt; uuencode $OP $OP) | mailx -s 'Subject' xxx@yy.com

OP=/tmp/hc.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

mailx -s "subject" emailaddress < $OP